# How to find the quickest path between many locations which have time restrictions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, path-finding, heuristics

I am trying to start on a personal research project that I have been brainstorming for a couple of years now. I am aware of graphs and algorithms for finding the best order in which to visit locations for the quickest time. However I am stuck on the next step of my research, are there research papers / algorithms that can solve this problem? Given a starting point and an end point with a number of "waypoints" that have to be visited. And some waypoints have time restrictions such as waypoint three has to be reached by 4:00 pm. So the algorithm will have to first sort the locations based on the time restrictions of them (if there are any) and then find the best order to visit each of the waypoints.

I have looked into many different algorithms/heuristics and I have searched for research papers on this topic but I cannot find anything definitive.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: I think that you may use any algorithm that finds a shortest path over the graph, but you should modify it in a way that it discards a solution (actually many solutions derived from this particular point) if you misses the time requirement at some point.

Comment: Be aware that "determine the order to visit the waypoints" is exactly the travelling salesman problem, which is NP-complete.

Comment: BlueRaja - I am fully aware of the type of problem it is, and I have written code that can determine the order of the waypoints, however I am wondering if there is an elegant real algorithm that will also take time restrictions into consideration.

Comment: Serge - that is definitely a way to do it, however I am hoping for another algorithm or type of sort that I can use.

Answer (score 2):

Never done anything like that but... elaborating on what has already told you BlueRaja, I have to say that most likely you already found your Grail (and, maybe, you are just not realizing it).

The time-related problem you are trying to solve looks like just another way to re-state the same space-related path-finding problem you already had to solve for travelling across your graph.

In other words, it looks like you have *two* graphs to traverse. The first one is the *spatial* one, represented by the net of waypoints you have to visit. The second one is the *temporal* (aka "time-related") graph of "time windows" you have to meet in order to not miss any bus/train/ship/airplane/whatever.

As long as I can see, you could use a regular path-finding/graph-crossing algorithm (Dijkstra, A*, contraction hierarchies, etc.) to traverse the spatial graph and re-use *the same* algorithm (or a very similar one) to traverse the time-related graph as well.

After all, both graphs are just a mathematical representation of a net of "constrains" (the points to be traversed, being them in space or in time) and can traversed using the same algorithm. Most likely, if you look at the code you are using to sort out your  "time windows", you will see that it is already quite similar to a very simple space-related graph-traversing algorithm.

The main problem seems to be finding a good representation of the temporal graph (the net of "time windows" you have to respect). Most likely, it will have to be a graph of time-constrained spatial waypoints (spatial points, or "doors", with a "time window" attached to each of them).

In any case, there is no way to solve two problems with one single operation. First, you will have to find the "shortest path" that connects all of your time windows (in the required order) in the temporal graph (that is: you have to sort them out, as you are already doing). Second, you will have to find the shortest paths between any pair of time windows in the spatial graph (and check if the shortest/fastest path is fast enough to meet the next time window).